# Custom Field cannot be sorted or filtered in Views for Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I have created a custom field for a View using a module. To better visualise here, I have simplified it: The custom field simply generates a random number between 1 and 10.

I want to "Sort by" this random number. However I receive the following error when using this setting in Views:

*SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'my_custom_field' in 'field list'*

I am struggling to locate the error in my code.

Thanks for any assistance you can provide in my module code!!

Here are my files:

**my_custom_module.info**

```
name = My Custom Module
description = Implement random number in views.
core = 7.x
files[] = includes/views_handler_my_custom_field.inc
```

**my_custom_module.module**

```
<?php
/**
 * Implements hook_views_api().
 */
function my_custom_module_views_api() {
  return array(
    'api' => 3,
  );
}
```

**my_custom_module.views.inc**

```
<?php
/**
 * Implements hook_views_data().
 */
function my_custom_module_views_data() {
  $data['my_custom_module']['table']['group'] = t('My custom module');
  $data['my_custom_module']['table']['join'] = array(
    // Exist in all views.
    '#global' => array(),
  );

  $data['my_custom_module']['my_custom_field'] = array(
    'title' => t('My custom field'),
    'help' => t('My custom field displays a random number.'),
    'field' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_my_custom_field',
      'click sortable' => TRUE,
    ),
    'sort' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_sort',
    ),
    'filter' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_filter_numeric',
    ),
  );

  return $data;
}
```

**views_handler_my_custom_field.inc**

```
<?php
/**
 * @file
 * Custom views handler definition.
 */

/**
 * Custom handler class.
 *
 * @ingroup views_field_handlers
 */
class views_handler_my_custom_field extends views_handler_field {
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   *
   * Perform any database or cache data retrieval here. In this example there is
   * none.
   */
  function query() {

  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   *
   * Modify any end user views settings here. Debug $options to view the field
   * settings you can change.
   */
  function option_definition() {
    $options = parent::option_definition();
    return $options;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   *
   * Make changes to the field settings form seen by the end user when adding
   * your field.
   */
  function options_form(&$form, &$form_state) {
    parent::options_form($form, $form_state);
  }

  /**
   * Render the random field.
   */
  public function render($values) {
    $random = rand(1, 10);
    return $random;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: you cannot sort a view without an appropriate database field.

A bit longer answer: `hook_views_data()`'s main purpose is to describe a database table to Views. You did display a field which does not really exist in the database using `'#global' => array()`, but due the fact that that particular field was not part of the SQL query, you simply cannot sort by it. Even the value of random number you got in `views_handler_my_custom_field->render()` method was generated after views produced and executed SQL query, in a moment when all the sorting already took place.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer! I now understand the logic better. Unfortunately I have to change the approach of my 'bigger picture' since this method will not work. The actual custom field I have created is dynamic according to the logged-in user (as with a contextual filter). Problem is that I require multiple contextual filters using an OR function between them and exposed for the user to play with. Time to find Plan B...